# How to analyze music MFCC?

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, mfcc

I'm trying to make a program for recognizing music instrument and notes(like C, C# B, ...) using machine learning in python.

I got data from IRMAS and philhamonic orchestra homepage.

How can I analyze music? I want to get noise removed and MFCC values. in 20 second music, I want to get within 20 featured values. I'm trying to use SVM using these data.

Sorry for too broad question... If there is something else i should mention, let me know then i'll answer imediately.

I have mathematica, also. I tried it using 'MFCC encoder' but i have no idea how can i normalize these data and set a threshold.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1383282) Mathematica example of using Neural Networks and MFCC encoding to classify music genre.